# Reference Request for Planned Economies

Tags: reference-request

I'm asking this board for resources and figures on the Soviet command economy, **specifically good places to start**.

I understand this question has political connotations, and that there are claims of obfuscation and misunderstanding from both command and market camps, but I am asking for the most perspicacious and academic assessment of the performance of the Soviet command economy. **I am skeptical about claims against its effectiveness.**

I would be interested in resources that support other countries attempting the command economy.

Comment: There are [half a million results on Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_vis=1&q=Soviet+command+economy&hl=en&as_sdt=1,5).

Comment: I recognize the abundance and appreciate your comment, but I think it would speak more to my request to the community for their insight  into which resources would be better starters. I am working through that list in different ways, and it is a lot of information...

Comment: Please edit this information (you are looking for "starter" references) into the body of your question. This will still likely leave hundreds of results, so further narrowing would be useful. What are you trying to understand, what economics education do you have so far, etc.

Comment: Gregory's *The Political Economy of Stalinism* is a reasonable starter for how the command economy got started in the Soviet Union.